# how does require jquery work in Rails 3 app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, require

In my rails 3 app it has:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery-ui
```

And it works fine. But I don't understand how it works. I think I understand the third line which I believe adds everything to this file that is found in the same directory as this file (/app/assets/javascript). But what about the first line? Where does it get the jquery file? I don't see it in any of the directories it mentions in the comment at the beginning of the file, specifically:

```
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
```

Where does rails go to get the jquery javascript file?

Comment: All three great answers. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The require part you mentioned above is called **asset pipeline**, which is part of new features of rails 3. The goal of this is to concatenate all javascripts file together, so you have your page load faster by a single import of the javascript file.

You can find out more about asset pipeline [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) and if not mistaken it is utilizing [sprockets gem](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets-rails).

Refering to **//= require jquery**, it is importing the javascript file from your jquery gem (only if you using jQuery gem). You can find it from your jQuery gem assets folder.

Refer this [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline) as it described best.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The screencast is great. Just the overview I needed. thanks for pointing me to it.

Comment: No problem. There is where I start to pickup the language too. cheers

Answer (score 2):

`require_tree .` includes *all* files under the directory it is in (e.g. app/assets/javascript). The jQuery source file come from the [jquery-rails gem](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets/javascripts)

Answer (score 1):

The comment can be a little confusing. A gem is also called a "plugin" in this case. It gets from the `jquery-rails` gem. Note the `vendor/assets/javascripts` structure.

https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets/javascripts